# How to convert a specific curl code to ruby code with restclient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

[image: API definition]I would like to convert  following `curl` code to `ruby`.

```
curl -u "my_username":"my_pass" \
     -X POST \
     -F "positive_examples=@/Users/abc/Downloads/tiger.zip" \
     -F "negative_examples=@/Users/abc/Downloads/leopard.zip" \
     -F "name=tiger" \
     "http://localhost/api/v2/class"
```

Finally, I could convert the curl example to Ruby, follow the example in ruby:

```
request = RestClient::Request.new(method: :post,
url: 'http://localhost/api/v2/class',
user: 'my_username', 
password: 'my_pass',
payload: {multipart:true, 
    positive_examples:File.new("/Users/abc/Downloads/tiger.zip", 'rb'),
    negative_examples:File.new("/Users/abc/Downloads/leopard.zip", 'rb')
    name:'tiger'})
```

Comment: Congrats! I added the mutipart argument to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RestClient::Request.execute method: :post,
                            url: 'http://localhost/api/v2/class',
                            user: 'my_username',
                            password: 'my_pass',
                            payload: {
                              multipart: true,
                              positive_examples: File.new('/Users/abc/Downloads/tiger.zip', 'rb'),
                              negative_examples: File.new('/Users/abc/Downloads/leopard.zip', 'rb'),
                              name: 'tiger',
                            }
```

Simply read the gem's [README](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#usage-raw-url).

Comment: I tried your example, but it could not work, follow the error message "RestClient::UnsupportedMediaType: 415 Unsupported Media Type".